# How to make hidden windows show up in alt-tab box

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to get a 'show desktop' shortcut to work, so I'm using 'hide all windows' shortcut to show the desktop. But after it hides the windows, I can no longer alt-tab through them, and I have to manually click on the unity bar to get back.

I would like alt-tab to switch through all of the applications open in my current workspace (including hidden ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can infer, I think you have configured in such a way that minimized windows will not show in the application switcher.

Install [compizconfig-settings-manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) and go to Ubuntu Unity plugin:

[image: Ubuntu unity plugin]

Navigate to switcher tab and check the option *Show minimized windows in switcher.*

[image: Alt-tab setting]

Comment: Wow, compizconfig can do anything!

Comment: This entry doesn't appear in CCSM in 15.04/Vivid Vervet, at least on my installation.  Are there any alternatives to using CCSM?  Is there a settings file or other power user tweak that controls this setting?  (I've tried the "Window Manager Tweaks" utility mentioned in ponsfrilus's answer, the utility doesn't start on my system.) I want to **exclude minimized windows** from the switcher, similar to OSX/Mac behavior -- this is not the case on my system, all windows are shown, minimized or not.

Answer (score 1):

Same possibility with Windows Manager Tweaks, as in the picture bellow.

[image: Windows Manager Tweaks]

Comment: Missing in Ubuntu 19.10. :(

Answer (score 0):

[Coverflow Alt-Tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/) does that beautifully on Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 with GNOME 3.34.3 DE and GNOME Shell WM according to `neofetch`.